# ActiveModel::Validation Any of 3 fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 fields in my Model and i need at least one of them to be present - how can do this using inbuilt validations?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: You need to add your own validation. There is not out of the box for this usecase.

Comment: You've asked about inbuilt validations, but the answer you picked does not comply with that in no way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom validation:

```
validate :one_of_three

def one_of_three
  errors.add(:base, 'Must have one of foo, bar or wee') unless foo || bar || wee
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
validate :attributes_presence 

def attributes_presence
  errors.add(:base, 'At least one attribute must be present') if attr1.blank? &&  attr2.blank? && attr3.blank?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to conditionally validate the presence of one attribute depending on presence of another:

```
validates :attr_1,
  presence: true,
  if: ->(model) { model.attr_2.blank? && model.attr_3.blank? }
validates :attr_2,
  presence: true,
  if: ->(model) { model.attr_1.blank? && model.attr_3.blank? }
validates :attr_3,
  presence: true,
  if: ->(model) { model.attr_1.blank? && model.attr_2.blank? }
```